# z-index not resetting to 0 on mouseleave for hovercard box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm somewhat new to jQuery. I'm using the hovercard plugin (http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/Hovercard) to bring up an interactive dialog modal when the user hovers over one of elements that represents an inventory item. The hovercard comes up by overlaying over the other elements on the page by setting the z-index to 200.

This works fine when I go slow enough, but when I zip my mouse over too many elements too quickly, the z-index for the previous element gets stuck at 200 and will not reset to 0.

What the hoverbox should look like (when hovered over item #46):
[image]

What the hovercard looks like when moving too fast:
[image]

I looked at the source for hoverbox, and found where they reset the z-indexes, and tried modifying the stop method values thinking the method was waiting for the animation to finish before resetting the z-indexes, but this did nothing to fix the problem.

Line 187 - 199 (full source: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40036711/jquery.hovercard.js)

```
function () {
                //Undo the z indices 
                $this = $(this);

                $this.find(".hc-details").eq(0).stop(true, true).fadeOut(300, function () {
                    $this.css("zIndex", "0");
                    obj.css("zIndex", "0").find('.hc-details').css("zIndex", "0");

                    if (typeof options.onHoverOut == 'function') {
                        options.onHoverOut.call(this);
                    }
                });
            }
```

**Relevant source from my page:**

HTML:

```
  <div class="users_current_inventory col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 item-thumbnail" id="users_current_inventory_32">32
  </div>
  <div class="users_current_inventory col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 item-thumbnail" id="users_current_inventory_40">40
  </div>
  <div class="users_current_inventory col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 item-thumbnail" id="users_current_inventory_45">45
  </div>
  <div class="users_current_inventory col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 item-thumbnail" id="users_current_inventory_46">46
  </div>
  <div class="users_current_inventory col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 item-thumbnail" id="users_current_inventory_47">47
  </div>
  <div class="users_current_inventory col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 item-thumbnail" id="users_current_inventory_48">48
  </div>
  <div class="users_current_inventory col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 item-thumbnail" id="users_current_inventory_49">49
  </div>
  <div class="users_current_inventory col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 item-thumbnail" id="users_current_inventory_50">50
  </div>
  <div class="users_current_inventory col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 item-thumbnail" id="users_current_inventory_51">51
  </div>
  <div class="users_current_inventory col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 item-thumbnail" id="users_current_inventory_52">52
  </div>
  <div class="users_current_inventory col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 item-thumbnail" id="users_current_inventory_53">53
  </div>
```

jQuery and Hovercard:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var hoverHTMLDemoBasic = '<p>sup</p>'

    $(".users_current_inventory")
    .hovercard({
      detailsHTML: hoverHTMLDemoBasic,
        openOnBottom: true,
        width: 500,
        cardImgSrc: 'http://ejohn.org/files/short.sm.jpg'
    });
});
```

**Some additional ideas I have about this problem:**

- I am using a class which is shared between inventory elements, so the
  quirks may be coming from that (although I switched to use the ids of
  each element as a test, and the issue was still happening).
- I need to use a plugin such as hoverIntent
  (http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) to
  prevent bubbling.
- I need to somehow find the element id and apply the hovercard to the 
  id rather than the shared class. (I know I can find the parent class 
  and then do `this.id` to find the id of the element hovered over, but
  I'm unsure of how to find the id of an element without first calling 
  .mouseenter, .mouseover, or .hover).

Any help/insight would be *GREATLY* appreciated!

Comment: It's nice to see a well formed context question. Especially from a new user. Any chance we get a live demo link ?

Comment: You can go here, http://nori.nu/, but the page will require you to login. Once you login, the page in question will be the Profile page (http://nori.nu/profile). You will need to find and save some 'items' in order to populate your inventory at this time. You can do this by clicking the 'Game' tab on the navmenu and clicking any of the 4 buttons (Gather Material, Light Button, Medium Button, Heavy button) and then clicking 'Save' once the item is generated. Sorry for all the hoops, but that would be a live example for you.

Comment: Humm, sorry, i wont create an account. If per anychance you create a working context, notify me. I'm interested in helping you. But, i noticed your jQuery mignt use a .each() and, i cannot see where obj is defined. Any javascript errors on your console ?

Comment: Oh, i forgot, you can try on the chat boards, there might be someone live and available to help you. It's under the top left Stackexchange button. Some of them are bug freak and with a little luck, you'll get a better help. Good luck

Comment: Hello Milche,
I got it working in jsfiddle. Here is the fiddle. The hovercard.js is an external resource if you need to look at that. http://jsfiddle.net/KAgu7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's weird, code-wise it seems to be doing the right thing, though maybe the function just isn't running quick enough to catch up. I also suspect that the `.stop()` function might be doing some black magic that is unknown but i don't even know.

Regardless, simply unsetting the `z-index` instantly post hover and letting the rest of the function still do its thing seems to be working in this instance.

**handy link:** http://jsfiddle.net/KAgu7/1/

**Relevant Lines:**

```
// ...Line 188

    //Undo the z indices 
    $this = $(this);

    //this is where I unset the z-index
    $this.css('z-index','');


    $this.find(".hc-details").eq(0).stop(true, true).fadeOut(300, function () {
        $this.css("zIndex", "0");
        obj.css("zIndex", "0").find('.hc-details').css("zIndex", "0");

        if (typeof options.onHoverOut == 'function') {
            options.onHoverOut.call(this);
        }
    });
});
// .. Line 198 ( now 199 )
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixes the issue for my purposes, so I'll mark it as accepted. Cheers